# why do aliases cause my query to fail in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The following query works fine in my php script, but when I run it in phpMyAdmin (against the same database), I get no results (not even "0 results" -- it just refreshes the page).

```
  SELECT comment, username, image, post_date, ((us.user_id != 22) AND

        ((SELECT read_date FROM
        bookmarks WHERE
        product_id=456029 AND
        user_id=22) < post_date)) AS
        new_comment FROM

        comments AS
        co, users AS
        us, flair WHERE co.product_id=456029 AND
        co.user_id=us.user_id AND
        flair_id=us.active_flair_id ORDER BY
        co.post_date ASC
```

I noticed that if I take out the aliases, the query works in phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT comment, username, image, post_date, ((users.user_id != 22) AND

        ((SELECT read_date FROM
        bookmarks WHERE
        product_id=456029 AND
        user_id=22) < post_date)) AS
        new_comment FROM

        comments, users, flair WHERE comments.product_id=456029 AND
        comments.user_id=users.user_id AND
        flair_id=users.active_flair_id ORDER BY
        comments.post_date ASC
```

I am curious why this would happen. (running phpMyAdmin - 2.11.9.5)

EDIT: Richard's reformulation below works in phpMyAdmin. So now the puzzle is why one formulation works and the other doesn't (when they both work fine when executed in a php script).

the final form of the query following Richard's advice to remove the subquery:

```
SELECT c.comment AS 
COMMENT , username, image, DATE_FORMAT( c.post_date,  '%b %D, %Y' ) AS post_date, IF( (
(
b.read_date IS NULL
)
OR (
b.read_date < c.post_date
) ) , IF( c.user_id !=1, 1, 0 ) , 0
) AS new_comment
FROM comments c
INNER JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN flair f ON flair_id = u.active_flair_id
LEFT JOIN bookmarks b ON ( b.product_id = c.product_id
AND b.user_id =1 ) 
WHERE c.product_id =538968
ORDER BY c.post_date ASC
```

Comment: `2.11.9.5`?  Even if you have to run 2.11.x for PHP4, that's not even the newest version of that series (and if you're still on PHP4, shame on you ;) ).

Comment: Does it fail with some kind of error, or merely not return any results?

Comment: @galador sadly it's a shared server, I have no control over it.

Comment: @Michael no there is no error message of any kind. page just reloads looking exactly the same

Comment: @jela: you always have control (by switching to another host).  :-)  I would be wary of any host that is still on PHP4, when it was [End-Of-Life'd at the end of 2007](http://www.php.net/archive/2007.php#2007-07-13-1).  Heck, even [PHP 5.2 is at its end-of-life](http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-12-16-1) as of last year.

Comment: Can you not upload your own phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

You have a very weird query, I wouldn't accept it either...

```
   SELECT comment, username, image, post_date
        , (
              (users.user_id != 22) 
          AND (
                  (
                       SELECT read_date 
                         FROM bookmarks 
                        WHERE product_id=456029 
                          AND user_id=22
                  ) 
              < post_date)
         ) AS new_comment 
    FROM comments, users, flair 
   WHERE comments.product_id=456029 
     AND comments.user_id=users.user_id 
     AND flair_id=users.active_flair_id 
ORDER BY comments.post_date ASC
```

little rewrite:

```
     SELECT comment, username, image, post_date
          , (
                (u.user_id != 22) # What is this for? First you check if it is not user 22
            AND (
                    (
                       SELECT read_date 
                           FROM bookmarks 
                         WHERE product_id=456029 
                            AND user_id=22  # And now you check if it is
                    ) 
                < post_date)
           ) AS new_comment 
      FROM comments c
INNER JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.user_id 
INNER JOIN flair f ON flair_id = u.active_flair_id 
     WHERE c.product_id = 456029 
  ORDER BY c.post_date ASC
```

What is your goal with this query? Surely this can be written better...

How about this:

```
    SELECT c.comment, username, image, c.post_date
         , IF(b.read_date < c.post_date, 1, 0) AS new_comment 
      FROM comments c
INNER JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.user_id 
INNER JOIN flair f ON flair_id = u.active_flair_id 
 LEFT JOIN bookmarks b ON (b.product_id = c.product_id AND b.user_id = u.user_id)
     WHERE c.product_id = 456029 
  ORDER BY c.post_date ASC
```

There is no reason in your query to use a subquery.

Comment: 'u.user_id' references a different table from 'user_id' in the subquery. The new_comment value is TRUE if the bookmark associated with a given product_id and user_id is older than the date a given comment was posted, otherwise FALSE. the (u.user_id != 22) qualifier ensures that if the comment was originally posted by this user himself, the comment is never marked as new (always FALSE). the reason for this is that if a user wrote the comment, he has by default read it.

Comment: I tested your query and it works fine in phpMyAdmin. I like your INNER JOIN syntax better than my formulation. I'm still puzzled by why one formulation would work but not the other.

Comment: Are you sure your queries are 100% the same? I assume the query executed in a php script has variables in there, perhaps there is a slight diffrence? (can't really see why that would happen though...)

Comment: Check my latest addition to above solution!

Comment: I have used your advice to remove the subquery. I had to made a couple changes to your query to make it do the same thing as the original. Specifically, the query is supposed to return TRUE for new_comment for each comment where the bookmark associated with the session user (not the user who posted the given comment, as in your query) is older than the post_date of the comment. Also new_comment should be TRUE if no bookmark exists, and FALSE for any comment where the session user is the same as the user who posted the comment. I edited the question with this query. Thanks again.

Comment: Alright. This query should be faster as well! Don't forget to accept the answer ;-)